# Why are my vectors being reset instead of having their own value?

Tags: c#

I'm studying programing right now and I need to make a "bus". I've got a vector with 25 spots and user will fill these with passengers. I've got a switch-case menu so you can choose if you want to add a passenger or get the full passenger list and so on. When I've entered about 5 passengers and want to get the passenger list everyone on the bus turns to 0 instead of the age I entered. I have no idea what's wrong?

Comments in the code are in Swedish.

```
{
    class Buss
    {
        public int[] passagerare;
        public int antal_passagerare ;


        public void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the awesome Buss-simulator");

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Välj alternativ");
                Console.WriteLine("1: Lägg till passagerare");
                Console.WriteLine("2: Skriv ut listan över passagerare");
                Console.WriteLine("3: Skriv ut total åldern över passagerna");
                Console.WriteLine("4: Skriv ut medelåldern över passagerarna");
                Console.WriteLine("0: Avsluta programmet.");

                string str = Console.ReadLine();
                int temp = Convert.ToInt32(str);



                switch (temp)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Lägg till passagerare (ange ålder endast)!");
                        add_passenger();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Skriv ut gästlistan!");
                        print_buss();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("hejsan");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("hejsan");
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        Console.WriteLine("hejsan");
                        break;
                }



                //ska ändra så att om man väljer 0 så stängs programmet

            } while (true);


            //Här ska menyn ligga för att göra saker
            //Jag rekommenderar switch och case här
            //I filmen nummer 1 för slutprojektet så skapar jag en meny på detta sätt.
            //Dessutom visar jag hur man anropar metoderna nedan via menyn
            //Börja nu med att köra koden för att se att det fungerar innan ni sätter igång med menyn.
            //Bygg sedan steg-för-steg och testkör koden.
        }

        //Metoder för betyget E

        public void add_passenger()
        {




            passagerare = new int[25];

            if (antal_passagerare < 25)

            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ålder på passagerare nr " + antal_passagerare);
                string age = Console.ReadLine();
                int age2 = Convert.ToInt32(age);
                passagerare[antal_passagerare] = age2;
                Console.WriteLine(passagerare[antal_passagerare]);
                antal_passagerare++;
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bussen är full!");
            }
            //Lägg till passagerare. Här skriver man då in ålder men eventuell annan information.
            //Om bussen är full kan inte någon passagerare stiga på
        }

        public void print_buss()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < antal_passagerare; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(passagerare[i]);
            }

        }

        // public int calc_total_age()
        //{

        //}


        //public int calc_average_age()
        //{

        //}



        public void find_age()
        {

        }

        public void sort_buss()
        {

        }



    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var minbuss = new Buss();
            minbuss.Run();
            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use `List<int>` instead of `int[]`, that way you don't need to keep track of how full the array is and do `passagerare.Length < 25` and `passagerare.Add(age2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am understanding this correctly, you are setting the array:

```
passagerare = new int[25];
```

to a new array every time you get into the `add_passenger` function so altthough you may actually set it the first time, the next time the user gets into the function, it'll be reset again.

If this is the case, the you can simply define it before you call this function and pass it as a parameter.

EDIT: In regards to your comment, you can define it in one of two palces.

1) You can create a constructor that sets the array to a length of `[25]` such as:

```
public Buss(){
    passagerare = new int[25];
}
```

2) You can define it before you enter your `switch` statement and pass the array into to each function as a parameter.

Comment: okey, iam really really new to programing. so i didnt understand much. but i think i understand, when im chosing option 1 im going back into the add_passenger codeblock and since there is passagerare = new int[25] im resetting it.  where should i define it to not make this happen??

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help. i tried this and now every passagers age returns as 0 when i press "2" for the questlist.

here is what i changed. see my comment.

Comment: @JonatanJohansson Are you sure? I've ran the exact code you have with that change and it works fine

Comment: @JonatanJohansson No problem, be sure to mark this as the correct answer if you found it helpful

Comment: kinda new to this site, if i have more problems? should i make another post or can i just post it in this one? @JamesS

Comment: @JonatanJohnansson It really depends on what the question is